# Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS hangs at boot

Tags: boot

I have a Dell Latitude 2120 small laptop with an Intel Atom (N550) CPU that has run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for a year or so.  Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  The boot process gets to the "moving dots" stage, the mouse cursor arrow eventually appears, but it is frozen and the system hangs at the dots stage.  I have tried boot-repair to no avail.  The system boots successfully from the "live USB" drive, but not on its own.

There is some web traffic that suggests that (1) Intel Atom needs a 32-bit system for Ubuntu and (2) 32-bit ISOs are no longer available from Ubuntu.  Is there a solution to this?